# netduino SPI stops clock after write on WriteRead()

Tags: spi, netduino

I am having an issue where the SPI bus on my netduino stops the SCK clock generator after the write has completed on a WriteRead() method. Because of this, the device (a Microchips 25LC320 EEPROM doesn't send any data.) Any help as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Source code:

```
SPI.Configuration config = new SPI.Configuration(Pins.GPIO_PIN_D10, false, 1, 1, false, false, 1000, SPI.SPI_module.SPI1);
SPI bus = new SPI(config);

byte[] write = new byte[] { 5 };
byte[] read = new byte[1];

spi.WriteRead(write, read);
```

Schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmajym.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Saleae capture:

[image: Analyzer screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a SPI interface, you need to do "dummy" writes in order to provide the clock cycles required to get data back from most devices. Try something like this:

```
byte[] write = new byte[] { 5, 0, 0 };
byte[] read = new byte[3];

spi.WriteRead(write, read);
```

After this executes, you should have a "garbage" byte in `read[0]` (this was the data on MISO during the first 8 clocks) and then two bytes from the memory in `read[1]` and `read[2]`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll have to let the people in charge of the Netduino site ensure this makes it to the wiki so people aren't confused.